# Not able to access public_html images from application deployed in tomcat

Tags: cpanel, tomcat

I an using cpanel at server ther I have deployed my application on tomcat7 to deploy a java war file.
I have saved images on public_html folder like`public_html/img/image1.jpg`
My problem is I am unable to access images from my site which are deployed in tomcat7.
If it is due to any file pesmission please suggest me what permission it should have?

How to resolve this problem?

Comment: Likely because you need to change ownership (chown) or folder/file permissions (chmod). Please edit your question and include these details.

Comment: I have edited please see

Comment: Use some trouble-shooting skills: to see if it is file permissions, experiment.  Try 777 and see if that works.  If not, then it is not permissions.

Comment: no not able to acces. I accessed images from other domain but I am not able to access with this domain